# Sublime Text: Highlight, bold, or underline text

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'd like to be able to highlight (or bold, or underline) important sections of code or other text so they stand out as I write. Sublime Text has a lot of advanced highlighting features, but how can I do a simple highlight like I would in Word or OpenOffice?

Comment: You can either have all text typed normal, all bold, all italics, etc... but I don't think Sublime allows bolding only specific words in a document, and I don't know of any package that can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to write a custom plugin to do that. For a bit of a head start i'd suggest using [BracketHighlighter](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/BracketHighlighter) then it's a simple matter of modding the regex expressions already present in the plugin to bold what you want.